# PYTHON Beautiful Soup Web Scraping Handling Dynamic Values

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The below HTML code has dynamic attributes for different individual series.  Example, one series can have multiple units, like Million or Thousands.

```html
    <tr class="series-pager-title">

<td valign="top" colspan="2">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
            <a href="/series/TOTALSA" style="font-size:1.2em" class="series-title">Total Vehicle Sales</a>
        </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-2">
     <span style="padding-left:49px;" class="popularity_bar">&nbsp;</span>     <span class="popularity_bar_background">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="series-pager-attr">

<td colspan="2">
      <div class="series-meta series-group-meta">
  <span class="attributes">Monthly</span>
  <br class="clear">
  </div>
  <div class="series-meta">
    
      <input class="pager-item-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="sids[0]" value="TOTALSA">
    
        <a href="/series/TOTALSA">
            Millions of Units,       
  
        Seasonally Adjusted Annual Rate 
      
  </a>
    <span class="series-meta-dates">
    Jan 1976
   to 
    Jul 2017
    
    (4 days ago)
    </span>
    <br class="clear">
  
            
    
      <input class="pager-item-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="sids[1]" value="TOTALNSA">
    
        <a href="/series/TOTALNSA">
            Thousands of Units,       
  
        Not Seasonally Adjusted 
      
  </a>
    <span class="series-meta-dates">
    Jan 1976
   to 
    Jul 2017
    
    (4 days ago)
    </span>
    
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" style="font-size:9px">&nbsp;</td></tr>

            
    <tr class="series-pager-title">

<td valign="top" colspan="2">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
            <a href="/series/ALTSALES" style="font-size:1.2em" class="series-title">Light Weight Vehicle Sales: Autos and Light Trucks</a>
        </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-2">
     <span style="padding-left:46px;" class="popularity_bar">&nbsp;</span>     <span class="popularity_bar_background">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="series-pager-attr">

<td colspan="2">
      <div class="series-meta series-group-single">
    <input class="pager-item-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="sids[2]" value="ALTSALES">
   
  <span class="attributes" style="width:350px;">Millions of Units, Monthly, Seasonally Adjusted Annual Rate</span><span class="series-meta-dates">Jan 1976 to Jul 2017 (4 days ago)</span>
  <br class="clear">
  </div>
    
          <a href="/series/ALTSALES">
      
  
  
  </a>
      
</td>
```

This gets me somewhat close, however it fails to obtain the 2nd frequency for the "Total Vehicle Sales," it only obtains the first "Millions of Units, Seasonally Adjusted Annual Rate."  Aside from this issue, my assumption is that I would be mis-classifying things in general with my current query.  Code I have created thus far:

```
    browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='F:\Anaconda\chromedriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get('https://fred.stlouisfed.org/categories/32993')
    soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,'lxml')

    for l in soup.find_all('tbody'):
        series_count=len(l.find_all('tr',attrs={'class':'series-pager-title'}))
        series_data=l.find_all('tr',attrs={'class':'series-pager-title'})
        attrs_data=l.find_all('tr',attrs={'class':'series-pager-attr'})
        print(series_count)
        print(len(attrs_data))
        for m in range(0,series_count):
            print(series_data[m].find('a',href=True).text+'  |  '+attrs_data[m].find('a',href=True).text.strip().replace('  ',' '))
```

In the above query, can someone please assist in creating the desired outcome:

[image]

Comment: For educated users reading my question, am I posing this question correctly or in a coherent fashion?  The ask is due to not having any responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone comes across this with a better solution I am all ears...  In the interim, this seems to do the trick...

```html
browser.get('https://fred.stlouisfed.org/categories/32993')
soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,'lxml')

test=soup.tbody
children=[child for child in test if child != '\n']

series_data=pd.DataFrame([],columns=['series_index','series_title','series_href'])
sub_series_data=pd.DataFrame([],columns=['series_index','frequency','sub_series_units','sub_series_href'])
series_index=0
for index,child in enumerate(children):
    if child.find('a',attrs={'class':'series-title'}):
        series_index+=1
        series_title=child.text.strip()
        series_link=child.find('a',href=True).attrs['href']
        
        temp_series_df=({'series_index':series_index,
                         'series_title':series_title,
                         'series_href':series_link})
        series_data=series_data.append([temp_series_df],ignore_index=True)
                
    if child.find('div',attrs={'class':'series-meta'}):
        frequency=child.find('span',attrs={'class':'attributes'}).text.strip()
      
        for i in child.find_all('a',href=True):  
            temp_sub_series_df=({'series_index':series_index,
                                 'frequency':frequency.strip(),
                                 #'sub_series_units':i.text.strip(),
                                 'sub_series_units':re.sub(' +',' ',re.sub('\n',' ',i.text)),
                                 'sub_series_href':'https://fred.stlouisfed.org'+i.attrs['href']})
            sub_series_data=sub_series_data.append([temp_sub_series_df],ignore_index=True)

print(series_data)
print(sub_series_data)

combine_series_data=pd.merge(series_data,sub_series_data,how='left',on=['series_index'])
```